# Draw polylines given distance & azimuth

Tags: qgis, line, digitizing

I am trying to draw a polyline from a single reference point. I have each specific segment of the lines Azimuth & distance. In the sequence I have areas where my line shifts over +90 / -90 of the current azimuth and then continues with the next azimuth below. I would like to preferably import these via excel and produce a record in the attribute table where I can see each segments spatial extent so I can take the Easting / Northing from the midpoint and incorporate that into an outside table. I have tried Azimuth and bearing but am having issues with it and I have to create a line for each segment. I tried advanced digitizing tools but the reference angles are from +- 90 N/S and +- 180 E/W which I could convert but seems like a hassle. Wondering if there is an easier way or if I have missed something? Here is an example database.

```
0.00    0.50    273 
0.50    1.00    285 
1.00    1.50    278 
1.50    2.00    295 
2.00    2.00    385 // Offset
2.00    2.30    283 
2.30    2.60    283 
2.60    3.05    285 
3.05    3.55    285 
3.55    3.85    270 
3.85    4.35    270 
4.35    4.75    270 
4.75    5.25    270
```

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS

Answer (score 2):

There is an [Azimuth and Distance Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAzimuth/) which can be used to import a data list of azimuth and distance information to draw polylines. I never used it before, but it looks like the plugin can do what you want.

[image]

Here is a tutorial on how to use the plugin: [QGIS: Azimuth and Distance Plugin](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-azimuth-distance-plugin)

Your data should be separated by semicolon `;` in order to be able to import the data:

```
0.00;0.50;273 
0.50;1.00;285 
1.00;1.50;278 
1.50;2.00;295 
2.00;2.00;385
2.00;2.30;283 
2.30;2.60;283 
2.60;3.05;285 
3.05;3.55;285 
3.55;3.85;270 
3.85;4.35;270 
4.35;4.75;270 
4.75;5.25;270
```

Here is after the output when I changed the delimeter to use semicolon instead of space

[image]

However, I am not sure about your data whether they should be organized like that or not, so you have to make sure, especially the 3rd column.

Comment: Do you know where I could find Importing help? I tried following their format but I get errors in the tables. As well I tried exporting a few rows to see what I could get but excel wont open it.

Comment: I updated my answer. I am not aware of any help document, but I could import your data properly. You need o use semicolon `;`

Comment: No definitely helpful. The third column was mostly just a reference of my idea. I played around with the plugin and can do it manually but this is greatly going to reduce the tinkering and time this would take. Thanks. I also figured out how to get the midpoint of the line which saves me even more time / errors