# Creating line from points that go outward from single point (2d plot of wellbore) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I am trying to create a 2d plot of a directionally drilled oil well. I have a surface location with coordinates and I need to create the borehole using this data from the measurements while drilling survey:

[image: MWD Survey]

as you can see, it gives an azimuth and coordinates in N/S ft and E/W ft.

The finished product would look something like this:

[image: Horizontal well plot]

Can you point me in the right direction?

I'm using QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Azimuth and Distance Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAzimuth/) as in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289755/98784). After installation it can be accessed via Plugins > Topography.

You will just need to extract your azimuth and distances (presumably "course length") and save only those two columns as a *semicolon*-delimited csv (not comma-delimited).

---

Here is what I tried using the data you provided:

#### Step 1

Extract azimuth and distances to a semicolon-delimited .csv (opened in a text editor below):

[image]

#### Step 2

Open the plugin. Under Options, configure the Survey Type as Boundary, Angle Type as Azimuth, Distance Unit as Feet, and Angle Unit as Gradian.

[image]

#### Step 3

Under the Drawing tab, import the .csv from earlier. If it works correctly you should see it populate the table. If not try and review your csv. Open it in a text editor if needed to double check the formatting.

Choose the active layer (must be linestring geometry) to draw on, or a memory layer, and select a starting point.

[image]

#### Step 4

Click 'Draw'. You may see a popup box that has nothing in it, just ignore it.

This is the result I got (keep in mind I'm using the wrong CRS and made up a point).

[image]

Closeup of the start:

[image]